# c# filter a two dimensional double array with another two dimensional double array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there any efficient way to filter a two dimensional double array with another two dimensional double array in c#?

For example, given two arrays as

```cs
    double[,] unfiltered = new double[ , ] {{1, 1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 7, 8, 9}};
    double[,] filter = new double[ , ] {{1, 1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5, 6}};
```

At the end, I would like to have an array like,

filtered = {{3, 7, 8, 9}},

filtered by the first column of each row.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Don't know about efficiency, but you can calculate hashes of inner arrays and compare two resulting arrays to get indexes of similar elements.

Comment: Thanks zloidooraque. I can easily append to a list with a custom for loop all the indices of similar elements. Then, according to this list I can create a new array with rows of non-repeated elements. However, I guess that when I will have a very big set of data, this will not be very efficient. Do you have any example with hashes? Or, I saw that there is the linq::where method. However, I haven't figured out yet a way to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

you're sure you want to use double for such numbers ?.
if possible use int, they calculate faster and require less memory.
Your filtering on whole rows of data it seams, looks like some graphic function.
Perhaps you could put them in a dictionary and then remove the indexed rows by row ID. Or use Array.Copy to copy from a certain index into a new array.